# Can I create a split screen in Mapbox-gl.js like I can in mapbox.js?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to do a split screen like in the old mapbox.js example
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/swipe-layers/

Any ideas on how to do this in mapbox-gl.js?

My only idea is to create a second map over the first map, clip it with the DOM width and then have the two maps respond to each others' bounding box changes. But with all my symbols and tooltip this would be tricky.

Answer (score 4):

Good news! There's a [pre-built plugin that provides this functionality](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-compare/).